# How to extend Class method and effect its subclass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

for instance:

```
class Kls {

}

class SubKls extends Kls {

}

Kls.metaClass {
    trySmth() {}
}

new SubKls().trySmth()
```

I hope SubKls can invoke extended-method #trySmth

**Update**: maybe i can use #invokeMissingMethod to solve it, but it's not enough, since I also wanna extend some Core Class such as java.lang.Object and java.lang.String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with groovy 2.4.0:

```
class Kls {}

class SubKls extends Kls {}

Kls.metaClass {
  foo = {'bar'}
}

assert new SubKls().foo() == 'bar'
```